# Linq query for latest status in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

[image: part of my db]
So, I have aggregation (PipelineJobStatus) of db.Pipeline and db.JobStatus
For one PipelineID I may have multiple statuses. I want to find the last one, and in viewbag to call it, in order to preview on Edit.cshtml
I need linq for that. I am trying like this:

```
 private IQueryable<StatusPipelineMerge> returnStatusOnID()
    {
        var test = (
           from users in db.PipelineJobStatus
           from pipe in db.Pipelines
               .Where(pipe => pipe.PipelineID == users.PipelineID).DefaultIfEmpty()
           from status in db.JobStatus
               .Where(statuses => statuses.JobStatusID == users.JobStatusID).DefaultIfEmpty()
           from fco in db.FCOes
                .Where(fcoes => fcoes.FCOID == pipe.FCOID)
           from client in db.Clients
           .Where(clients => clients.ClientID == pipe.ClientID)
           orderby users.CreatedTimeStamp descending
           select new StatusPipelineMerge
           {
               JobStatusName = status.JobStatusName
           }
            );
        return (test);
    }
```

I've put descending for the reason, to just grab then first date on stack (FirstOrDefault).Can I do that? Or I need MAX function?
I am using EF6
Thanks!

Comment: That seems overly an complicated number of joins, just to get the status from one table for a given client job. Most of the data fetched by the SQL is then thrown away.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it.."Lazy" approach is not quite good, but this is a small-scale application, if you understand. Cheers

Comment: Yes, I understand "Lazy" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the famous Northwind sample database with EF:

```
    var lastPurchaseCustomer =
(from o in Orders
 orderby o.OrderDate descending
 select new
 {
   TheID = o.Customer.CustomerID
 }).FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(lastPurchaseCustomer.TheID);
```

Sends this SQL to server:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[CustomerID] AS [CustomerID]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[CustomerID] AS [CustomerID], 
    [Extent1].[OrderDate] AS [OrderDate], 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[OrderDate] DESC
```

And prints (I could get from Order.CustomerID too, but here could also ask for CompanyName, ContactName ... etc):

RATTC

Answer (score 2):

As you are ordering descending then `FirstOrDefault()` (assuming there might not be any will be what you want.

If you order ascending you would use `LastOrDefault()`.

Either is OK and go with the one that makes your code most understandable.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Let you know l8r.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that simply:

```
private StatusPipelineMerge returnStatusOnID()
{
  var test = (from users in db.PipelineJobStatus
     orderby users.CreatedTimeStamp descending
     select new StatusPipelineMerge
     {
       JobStatusName = users.JobStatus.JobStatusName
     }).FirstOrDefault();
  return (test);
}
```

I didn't understand the need for those joins nor the "left join" approach for such a relation between PipelineJobStatus and JobStatus.

Comment: I like your code, but unfortanetely, I have red underline on some code, 'Ambigious invocation'. And, users pseudo is for db.PipelineJobstatus, not for JobStatus, on that line is cannot resolve symbol :) Maybe I need to join JobStatus table? Cheers

Comment: But that is something done in your EDM model and called "navigation properties". IOW with a proper EDM model you could simply say user.JobStatus.JobName without using any join (dot notation). Probably there is something wrong in your model. You can download and check in LinqPad. Normally you should see a blue sybmol like  >- JobStatus when you expand PipeLineJobStatus. If not then EDM is not correct (or your code first model fluent syntax).
You may need to include it ( ,,, db.PipelineJobStatus.Include("JobStatus") ... )